# Data points shifting when I change X-axis to dates

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am trying to have my plot show dates for the X axis I posted pictures showing how the graph is supposed to look and what I would like to change.

[image: This is with integers for the X axis]

How do I get the figure below to have the error bars as the figure above to cover the figure below.

[image: Dates as X axis]

Comment: Its generated from a VBA code I have.

Comment: I don't understand why either of your answers solved the problem. Looks like the X values in your charts are simply the point numbers or maybe the numbers in column B. I mean, 8/1/1911? Is it a line chart or scatter chart? In either case, ensure that the code actually makes the chart point to the range of dates as X values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the *...** lines

```
   'GET RANGE FOR CHART X-AXIS LABELS
   got_label_range = True   ' True to re-activate the input range
   Set chart_labels = GetRange("Please select the range containing the LABELS" & Chr(13) & "(press ESC if no labels available)")
   **chart_labels.NumberFormat = "0.00"**
   If IsNotOk(chart_labels) Then
      got_label_range = False
   End If

   With .Chart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels
        .Alignment = xlCenter
        .Offset = 100
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .Orientation = xlHorizontal
        **.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"**
   End With
```